# Index not showing the results of a search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, search

[Edit] Changed some functions to make it more clear.
I am trying to make a search function where the user can input a query, and an API(https://github.com/games-directory/api-giantbomb) returns matching items. However nothing is appearing on my Index despite there not being any errors popping up when I search.

I decided to use the Rails LIKE feature to return the query results in my index as seen below.

```
  def index
  if params[:query].present?
      sql_query = "name LIKE :query"
      @games = Game.where(sql_query, query: "%#{params[:query]}%")
    else
     flash[:notice] = "No Games Found"
    end
  end
```

It redirects to the Index, but shows no games nor the flash message. Here is the index:
My index.html.erb that is supposed to return a list of games that match the query:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<ul>
  <% @games.each do |game| %>
    <li><%= game.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I can see the "Test" text, but nothing else after I conduct a search.

For reference, here is the rest of my GamesController.

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
//Displays search results
  def index
  if params[:query].present?
      sql_query = "name LIKE :query"
      @games = Game.where(sql_query, query: "%#{params[:query]}%")
    else
     flash[:notice] = "No Games Found"
    end
  end

//Searches through API data
  def search
    @games = GiantBomb::Search.new().query(params[:query]).resources('game').limit(5).fetch
    render 'index'
  end


private

  def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(:name, :search, :query)
  end
end
```

My routes just in case that is having any effect.:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :games
  root to: 'pages#home'
  get '/search', to: 'games#search', as: :search
  get '/games', to: 'games#index', as: :index
end
```

My search bar on my home page:

```
    <div class="search-font"><h1>Build your Collection</h1></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 row">
          <%= form_tag index_path, method: :get do %>
          <div class="col-12 col-sm pr-sm-0">
            <%= text_field_tag :query,
              params[:query],
              class: "form-control input-lg",
              id: "typed-text" %>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group-btn ml-3">
            <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What's the issue here? Do I need to revise my index method or is there another problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Its unclear what you're actually asking here and why you would expect this to work. You're defining the method `search` in your controller yet you're calling `Game.search(params[:query])` on your model with a different signature. Also don't just write "After doing some reading" - "I tried googling" etc which is just lame. List what you have actually researched as it gives vital clues as to where you went wrong.

Comment: I went ahead and edited my question to be more clear. I am trying to get the Index to display the search results of an API data. I revised my Index, but I am not seeing the results from my search.

Comment: So, when you click the submit button on your search form, it makes a get request to your index method on the games controller, right? For one, you have `game_params` defined, which is good and you should use strong params, but you aren't using it anywhere. For the time being, though, you should still have access to `params[:query]`. Do you use any debug tools, like byebug or pry? I would try and toss one in your index method and check to see if @games is empty.

Comment: When I run byebug my index seems to be working: SELECT "games".* FROM "games" WHERE (name LIKE '%QueryText%') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]. However when I change pararms to game_params I get: "param is missing or the value is empty: game" . So is :game somehow empty?

Comment: So, take a look at the parameter hash that is being sent. You’re currently passing in a parameter hash like `{query: ‘text you entered’}`, but with strong parameters and using game_params, you should be passing a hash that starts with the relevant model, like `{game: {query: ‘text you entered’} }`. Try changing that text field from `query` to `game[query]`that and see if it works.

Comment: On the home page? Right now I just have "<%= text_field_tag [:query], params[:query],". When I change it to game[:query] it says undefined variable for game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added it in a comment, but it looks like you’ll need to make sure you are passing in the correct parameter hash structure, where the model is included.

So, instead of passing `{query: ‘your text’}`, you’ll want to have it read as `{game: {query: ‘your text’} }`, in order for the strong params of `game_params` to pick it up. Your `name` property for the input would change from `query` to `game[query]` to nest it properly.

Comment: This isn't correct. First, index accesses query through params, not game_params, and second, game_params are only set if using form_for, not form_tag.

Comment: You’re absolutely right if we’re just looking at the code he has listed in his question, but from his comments it sounded like he had changed his code to use `game_params`, but had just not updated his code in the question to reflect it. So, I was going off of the assumption that he had updated the index action to use `game_params`, but needed to update his form to use the game model, too.